# Set up the size of backgound colour plot to the size of axes in seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using seaborn for create plot  according to [this example](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/joint_kde.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")

rs = np.random.RandomState(5)
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
x1, x2 = rs.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500).T
x1 = pd.Series(x1, name="$X_1$")
x2 = pd.Series(x2, name="$X_2$")

g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", size=7, space=0)
```

However, when I change the last line of code to

```
g = sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", size=7, space=0, xlim=(-5,5), ylim=(-5,5))
```

the background color does not change correctly:
[image]

How I can fix the background color so that it fills the whole plot?

Comment: So the problem here is that seaborn is only computing the KDE out to -4 and 4 in both dimensions. The real solution to this, IMO, is not to extend the palest blue (KDE=0) out to infinite bounds, but to force the lowest level of that color palette to the background shade of the axes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to tell the underlying function (`kdeplot`) to extend its KDE estimate farther out. This is accomplished through the `cut` argument, which is a function of the KDE bandwidth. It defaults to 3, and there's no obvious way to tell exactly how you need to set it, but it shouldn't be that hard to play around and find values that work. When using `jointplot`, you'll want to pass this in the `joint_kws` dictionary so that it gets sent to the appropriate plotting function.

```
sns.jointplot(x1, x2, kind="kde", size=7, space=0,
              joint_kws={"cut": 10},
              xlim=(-5,5), ylim=(-5,5))
```

Voila:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is very close, but I can't quite match the colour. If you find the colourmap in the cm module ("cool"?) you can find the exact colour.

```
ax = plt.gcf().axes[0]
ax.set_axis_bgcolor((.93,.93,1))
```

If you are doing this interactively, you will need a plt.draw() to have the new colour show.

Comment: By the way, although I think it's probably better to accomplish this when calling `jointplot` (as in my answer), if you're curious how to get this color you'd have to first assign the output of the function to a variable, call it `g`, and then do `g.ax_joint.collections[0].get_facecolor()`.